# php delete script

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a field in a sql database called `time_stamp` that timestamps when the record was added to the database.  I have another field called 'TTL', which will have either 1, 2, or 3 stored in it (each number within this field represents a day).  Can I have a php script where the deletion of the record is determined by the 'TTL' field?

For instance a record is added at noon today, with a 'TTL' of 2, can I have a script that deletes that same record at noon two days from now?

What would be the best way to do this, and do I really need both fields to execute this?

Comment: You want someone to write the script for you?

Comment: Not really, I was going to give it a stab but wanted to get a different perspective of how it should be done.  I am kinda stumped on where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best method for running this script is attaching it to `cron` and having it run on a given interval.

Then, in order to program the record deletion, you'll need to run the following query:

`DELETE FROM records WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) + TTL * 86400 <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

`time_stamp` is your record creation value - let's say it's equal to 1000000. 86400 is the amount of seconds in a day. `TTL` is the amount of days after `time_stamp` that you want the file deleted. So if `TTL` is 2 and 1000000 was the timestamp for July 10th, we are basically comparing:

1000000 + 86400 * 2 <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Now, let's say that today is July 12th. This means it's 2 days (86400 * 2 seconds) after July 10th. Thus,

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP = July 10th timestamp + 2 days worth of seconds
                  = 1000000 + 86400 * 2
```

Which implies `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= 1000000 + 86400 * 2` for all points in time during and after July 12th, thus deleting the record.

This will delete the records daily for you while your server is running. Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: This will delete the daily records but what if the user chooses for that record to delete after the second day or after the third instead of the first?

Comment: No, this will delete only the records that should be deleted on a given day. 86400 represents the `unix time` for a full day and acts as a condition for deletion (will only delete on the 2nd day if TTL = 2, 3rd day if TTL = 3, etc.)

Comment: I get it now thank you, but the UNIX_TIMESTAMP reference. Will that work if I am using current_timestamp with attributes of 'on update current_timestamp'?

Comment: Remove `on update current_timestamp`, it will update your `time_stamp` value and ruin your delete task completely. If you felt that I was of assistance, an upvote and accepted answer would be cool :) Enjoy!

Comment: okay, I might be a little more confused than I originally thought. Correct me where I'm lost, 86400 * 1 + timestamp will never be less than the current_timestamp correct?  I am not sure how this works.

Comment: @need2nobasis, explanation added. Enjoy!